# Make tableview rows interactable/selectable

Tags: swift, xcode, button, tableview

My case is that I have made a table view displaying an array of the users (one user per cell). I want to make it so when you press on one of the users name in the table view, it prints the name of that user in the console. This will allow me to do other things like segue into their profile ect. For more detail It would be something like this(although this doesn't work):

```
func selectTableViewRow {
   if rowButtonTapped = true {
      print(cell.selectedcell.textlabel.text!)
   }
}
```

I hope this makes sense, thanks a lot!

The found solution found in the comments

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(userArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: you need to make your func @IBACTION and link it back from your table in IB. You'll need a sender param.

Comment: Implement `didSelectRowAt` and get the data from the data source array, not from the cell.

Comment: yes, the didSelectRowAt does work. Is there anyway I can get it to print the name of the selected user? @vadian

Comment: As I said, get the item in the data source array at the given index path like in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: ok, I tried to get it like this(inside the didSelectRowAt); print(userArray[place for Int]). I just don't know how to get the Int of the selected row.

Comment: @WilliamCarter make sure to use `indexPath.row`.

Comment: yes this works! ill update it!